# Use TermExtractor in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, packagist

I would like to use a library called term-extractor (https://packagist.org/packages/fivefilters/term-extractor) in Laravel 5. I tried to install it via composer with

```
composer require "fivefilters/term-extractor:*"
```

I think, this step was sucessfull as i found the following directory: vendor/fivefilters/term-extractor. As well a line  was added to composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "fivefilters/term-extractor": "*"
    },
```

But from this point I don't know how to proceed.

Is the package really available to my app?
How may I use term extractor? If I try with

`$extractor = new TermExtractor();`

it doesn't work.

Thanks!

--

I follwed the advises given by Alan Storm - many thanks!

1. Running composer dumpautoload

   ```
   composer dumpautoload
   Generating autoload files
   ```

seems to be fine.

2. Running my code

   ```
   Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
   1/1 FatalErrorException in NewsletterController.php line 81: Class 'Fivefilters\TermExtractor' not found

   in NewsletterController.php line 81
   at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(array('type' => '1', 'message' => 'Class 'Fivefilters\TermExtractor' not found', 'file' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newsletterfeed/app/Http/Controllers/NewsletterController.php', 'line' => '81')) in HandleExceptions.php line 116
   at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
   ```

where we finde in line 81

```
$extractor = new TermExtractor();
```

Any suggestions what's going wrong? Many Thanks!

Comment: "Doesn't work" is no suitable error description. What is the exact error message? Did you include the Composer autoloader?

Comment: @carl Updated my question below -- don't forget to vote for things -- it helps ensure you get responses to future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is

1. Configure your `composer.json` file to use the `fivefilters/term-extractor` package
2. Used Composer to download the `fivefilters/term-extractor` package into your `vendor` folder

What you do next depends on how well the package developers have setup their package to play nice in the modern PHP world.

If you search for [the package on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/fivefilters/term-extractor), you'll find the source repository for the package is [at BitBucket](http://code.fivefilters.org/term-extraction.git).

If you look at [the package's `composer.json` file](http://code.fivefilters.org/term-extraction/src/cffa5af391acd59774851179daf6b606bcdee381/composer.json?at=master), you'll see it's setup with the following autoloader section

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { 
        "TermExtractor": "",
        "Tagger": "",
        "PermissiveFilter": "",
        "DefaultFilter": ""
    }
}
```

Without going into the full details (which is too long of an answer for StackOverflow -- see my [Laravel, Composer, and the State of Autoloading](http://alanstorm.com/category/laravel#container)), this `psr-0` sections means PHP should try to autoload the "TermExtractor" class from

```
vendor/fivefilters/term-extractor/TermExtractor.php
```

Laravel 5 is setup to automatically use Compoer's autoloader library.  This means, if you're writing code from a Laravel bootstrapped environment, all you should need to do is

```
$object = new TermExtractor();
var_dump(get_class($object));
```

If that doesn't work it means

1. The maintainers of `fivefilters/term-extractor` have an error in their autoloader logic
2. Composer isn't automatically running `composer dumpautoload` for you
3. You're not running your code from a Laravel bootstrapped enviornment (`app/routes.php`, a controller file, etc.)

I'd start by running

```
$ composer dumpautoload
```

and seeing if that helps.  If it doesn't posting the error, or what unexpected behavior happened, as well as where you're writing this code (back in your main question) will help people here help you diagnose what's wrong with your system.

**Update**: Based on the updated question, the following error

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>   1/1 FatalErrorException in NewsletterController.php line 81: Class > 'Fivefilters\TermExtractor' not found

Makes it sound like you're trying to run your code from a file that lives in the `Fivefilters` namespace.  i.e.

```
namespace Fivefilters
//... other code
$extractor = new TermExtractor();
```

That doesn't quite make sense -- based on the file the code is running from

```
app/Http/Controllers/NewsletterController.php
```

I'd expect the namespace to be `App\Http\Controllers`.  Regardless of that, it looks like the [five filters classes](http://code.fivefilters.org/term-extraction/src/cffa5af391acd59774851179daf6b606bcdee381/TermExtractor.php?at=master) all live in the global namespace.  This means if you want to use them from a namespaced PHP file, you'll need referrer to them either explicitly as global classes (leading `\`)

```
$object = new \TermExtractor;
```

Or use the `use` statement at the top of your file

```
namespace Some/Non/Global/Namespace
//...
use TermExtractor;
//...
$extractor = new TermExtractor();
```

Comment: Many thanks Alan!!  $object = new \TermExtractor; did the job!